# Codeplex MonoDevelop

Tags: svn, monodevelop, codeplex

Does MonoDevelop work with Microsoft's CodePlex using SVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it.

http://paulsiu.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/using-subversion-source-control-with-monodevelop/

http://blogs.msdn.com/codeplex/archive/2008/09/14/codeplex-launches-support-for-tortoisesvn.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Does MonoDevelop support SVN? Yes. Does Codeplex offer SVN interface? Yes. I guess the answer is Yes?